# Defining a list from scratch in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

So I need to define a list predicate: `list(.)` that returns true if the list is of the form `cons(b,cons(d,cons(e,cons(h,nil))))`. for the list `bdeh`.

I need to define the `cons(.,.)` binary predicate as well.

So far I have :

```
cons(atom(A),nil):- cons(A,nil).
cons(A,B):- cons(A, cons(B,_)).

list(atom(A)):-cons(A,nil).
list(A):- list(cons(_,A)).
```

but I don't think that the `list(.)` predicate is actually traversing through my cons. Can anyone help out in how to traverse the list or to proceed?

Comment: Why do you need to define `cons/2`? `cons/2` is **not** a predicate, it is a **functor**.

Comment: sorry I meant functor, I need to define it for an assignment

Comment: you do not need to define a functor. Prolog is a dynamic language: functors can be generated *on-the-fly*.

Comment: Can you explain the logic you think you wrote in your `list/1` predicate?

Comment: Furthermore I don't really see what `atom/1` is doing here either.

Comment: so for my list/1 predicate, I assumed that if it is being called with an atomic variable, that it is the only element in the list, so it being of the form cons(A,nil). would return true

Comment: the second line of that is me trying to recursively traverse through the list, kind of like ignoring the head and using the tail of the list only as the new list being called in list(.)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to define the `cons(.,.)` binary predicate as well.

Based on your question, **`cons/2` is not a predicate, it is a functor**. A functor has no *inherent* semantical meaning. A functor is used to *structure* data in some way that makes sense to the programmer.

Your predicate `list/1` needs to verify that the parameter is a list. Two things are lists:

- the `nil/0` constant; and
- a compound term of the functor `cons/2` where the **second element** is a list as well.

So we can define it like:

```
list(nil).
list(cons(_,X)) :-
    list(X).
```

**How does this work?** The first clause simply states that `nil` is a list: if you call `list(nil).` it will succeed ("return" `true`). If you do not give it a `nil`, it will check the *second* clause and see if you gave it a *compound term* of `cons/2`. If that is not the case the clause (and thus the predicate call) will fail. If it is the case, it will *unpack* the compound term. Prolog is *not* interested in the first element (that's why we call it `_`), the second element we name `X`, and Prolog will perform a recursive call to `list/1` with that second element to check if it is a list as well. Therefore it will traverse through the nested `cons/2` structures until it finds a `nil` (or cut off earlier if the second element is not a `nil` and not a `cons/2` compound term).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the explanation, definitely very helpful

Comment: It is `cons`, not `const`. It comes from the days of old: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons